# Grub2 is not being installed within installation of Ubuntun 14.04.3 and Win 10 set before

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

hope you can help a beginner. I recently upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 10.
After that I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.3 and successfully installed it;

For that I made several partitions;
One for Windows 10 with around 400gb ntfs,then 3 partitions of ext 4, one root partition where I installed Ubuntu with around 150gb, one /home with also 150gb, one /boot with 1gb; I also set a partition vor swap of 10gb and a fat32 20gb file system called /commonfiles to have a partition I can use for both, Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

However, the installation ended successfully but unfortunately, grub2 wasn't installed and Windows 10 normally started...

Does anyone have an idea how to get grub2 with entries for both, Win 10 and Ubuntu 14.04.3?
I'm unfortunately a bloody beginner and I don't rech the terminal of Ubuntu because I see no way in starting Ubuntu;

I would be extremely happy if someone can help...

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Look , if you installed Ubuntu using **UEFI** boot configuration then you can easily change the boot config to start Ubuntu from your BIOS configuration menu :

set the first **EFI** boot priority to :

Ubuntu boot manager

Save & Exit

then u can boot up you Ubuntu

and when you're done and have access to your terminal you can install grub using this command :

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX  # Example: sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

and don't forget to update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

Source :

[Ubuntu Official help content](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)

the above didn't work out you can try to fix boot using your installation disk/usb after booting into your installation media to "Try Ubuntu before installing" you can use  :

Boot-Repair

installation :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Source:

[Ofiicial Ubuntu Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

at last if none of the above works you can use a software :

> EasyBCD

for Windows ..
you can modify windows' boot manager very easily and you can add ubuntu to it but you'll get to your ubuntu using Windows' boot manager not ubuntu's grub .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great advice... I just tried Easy BCD because it sounded like a lot less of work and it really worked out totally easily; After installing I just added Ubuntu and then everything was done alright.... Thank you so so much!!!!! :)

Comment: you can verify my answer as correct to help the community and googlers